# do the same thing for every line in a text file

Tags: powershell, vbscript, batch-file

I have list of text file which contains the proxy IP addresses as below

```
192.168.1.5:8080
172.18.1.6:8080
195.68.1.7:8080
192.16.1.8:8080
192.15.1.9:8080
92.168.1.88:8080
12.185.1.45:8080
158.1.1.97:8080
```

Now what I want is to set the proxy address as mentioned in the text file above one at a time and then open a website www.example.com in Internet Explorer.

I just want to open the website with all the proxy addresses automatically.

How can this be done using either powershell, batch or vbs?

Comment: @Graimer or do you mean...."phishy"?

Comment: sry, misspelled New user + loop through proxies, I get a bad feeling. I'm not gonna provide a solution that could brute-force a login page. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can little modify following script http://poshcode.org/2897. The are also many examples how to modify proxy in powershell, so changing above scripts to your needs should not be difficult